# Not able to convert list to JSON with GSON with message "declares multiple JSON fields"

Tags: android, json, gson

I am trying to convert this list to json with the help of GSON

```
[DataClass(label=valueOne, text=some.value, version=9.0, ui=null, ref=null, icon=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@2f9631a), DataClass(label=valueOne, text=some.value, version=9.0, ui=null, ref=null, icon=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@2f9631a)]
```

And got this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
```

Here is how I do that

```
 Gson().toJson(list)
```

What might the be issue?

It complaint for some reason on this drawable source. But not sure why. I was thinking that its because of `@` and changed it to regular `Z` and still no success

Here is the value of drawable

```
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawableZ25d399b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson uses 'type adapters' to perform the conversion from Java object to JSON and vice versa. If no custom type adapter has been provided for a type, and Gson does not provide a [default one](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#built-in-serializers-and-deserializers) either, Gson uses reflection to determine how to convert Java objects to JSON and how to convert it back to a Java object. However, because it considers private fields, you should not rely on it when serializing or deserializing classes from third party libraries or from the Android Platform. The private fields of these classes are implementation-dependent and it is likely that they might be renamed or removed between versions, and might even differ between different Android devices.

Therefore, even though the exception is about a field named `mChangingConfigurations`, which apparently exists in the class `ColorStateList` as well as one of its superclasses, the main issue here is that you are trying to use Gson for serializing Android Platform classes.

To solve this, try to refactor your code to not store the `icon` as `BitmapDrawable` in JSON. Depending on your use case, maybe it would be possible to store the file path, or the URL of the icon instead. And then when reading the JSON again you have to reconstruct the icon.

As side note: The `toString()` output you showed at the beginning of your question is unrelated to how Gson performs the conversion. The string `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@2f9631a` just happens to be the [default `toString()` result](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object#toString()).

Comment: ye I refactored my logic to avoid using icon and walk around. There is no way to fix that if you need that value so I just saved that in separate list and than merge two lists